# Using the Linux tr command

Tags: linux

I need help with this question:

> If the process pipeline `echo "message" | tr a-wxyz d-zabc` represents (Caesar cipher) encryption, what represents decryption?

I've run this command in the question and it converts "message" to "phvvdjh", so it increased each letter by 3 (so m --> p, e --> h...).

How do I go back from "phvvdjh" to "message"?

I don't really know how the "tr" command works or how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the "to" section in tr with the "from" section

```
echo "phvvdjh" | tr d-zabc a-wxyz
```

its a letter for letter conversion, but is commonly confused with regex, such as 'sed'